# Undefined index: nombre in

Tags: php, html

Como puedo mantener los datos ingresados de un input al apretar el boton de enviar.

Ya busque en muchos lugares formas de poner el value pero todos me tiran error.

```
<input type="text" name="nombre" id="Nombre" placeholder="Nombre" class="name" value="<?php echo $_POST['nombre']?>">
```

Probé de varias formas y me tiran este error:

> **Notice**:  Undefined index: nombre in **C:\xampp\htdocs\SesionForm\index.php** on line **19**

Comment: Explica más el contexto, no se entiende lo que quieres hacer. ¿De dónde sacas esto: `$_POST['nombre']`? Parece como si quisieras llenar un formulario desde otro formulario ¿? ¿Es eso lo que quieres? ¿Por qué?

Comment: Tienes, dentro del pedazo de php, que comprobar que POST este iniciado en el value. `if(isset($_POST['nombre'])){echo $_POST['nombre']}`

Comment: Puedes controlar eso desde Javascrit usando `preventDefault()`. La idea de los formularios es enviar sus datos al servidor para procesarlos y que la página se recargue, borrándose todos los datos, a no ser que uses Ajax por ejemplo, donde podrías enviar/recibir datos desde/hacia el servidor sin necesidad de recargar la página.

Comment: @A.Cedano el solo quiere mantener cargado el input del dato que mandó. Solo basta leer de nuevo el $_POST para que cargue.

Comment: Ok, pero es muy extraño eso. Si OP aprende a usar Ajax esto no sería necesario... @Excorpion

Comment: Agrégale una respuesta de AJAX para que haga eso mismo, no creo que complique.

Answer (score 0):

Como dije, tienes que validar que $_POST este iniciado, sino no podrás mostrarlo.

```
<input 
type="text" 
name="nombre" 
id="Nombre" 
placeholder="Nombre" 
class="name" 
value="<?php if(isset($_POST['nombre'])){echo $_POST['nombre']} ?>">
```